# ProxyPass or intercept web requests .NET

Tags: .net, apache

I have got a .NET winform application that uses a Web Mapping Service that is password protected. Unfortunately I cannot  attach a username and password to requests, ( the request are generated from a GIS mapcontrol)

I can think of two ways around it

1. Intercept all web requests from my .NET app and add a username/password
2. Set up an Apache webserver and use proxypass to pass along my request adding a username/password

Does anyone know how to do either of these?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a password to a request (assuming they're using HTTP authentication instead of forms-and-cookie based authentication) is simply a matter of attaching a WWW-authenticate header to each request. You can find the details of how to encode the information here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Since you're always using the same user/password for all requests, you'll be attaching the exact same string to *every* request, making it dramatically easier to implement. The mechanism you use is up to you, but any sort of proxy mechanism that allows you to add a header will do.